# Customers list are not visible in odoo mobile crm application

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-mobile

In web application I have added the customers and I am fetching the res.partner model but i am not able to see the customers in mobile app.I have sync the customers but it is not visible.It shows no customers found.Where is the issue.If I will search in search view the list of customers is visible in mobile but it is not showing in list view.

Can anybody help me.

Comment: Are you using XML-RPC or ODOO Mobile Framework?

Comment: it will be more helpful if you post you code here